# how to get the transaction of site for each day laravel postgres

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

i want to take the sum of my transactions in my site for each day here is what i do to get the count of it :

```
  $results = Transaction::select(\DB::raw("TO_CHAR(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS month, COUNT(*) AS count"))
            ->groupBy(\DB::raw("TO_CHAR(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD')"))
            ->get();
        return $results;
```

i am getting the count of that currently and without any problem but i want to have the sum of field`amount` .now how can i get the sum of each day `amount` to see how much transaction my app had for each day .

Comment: Like adding `SUM(amount)` in addition to count?

Comment: add `sum(amount)` in `DB::raw()`